# Javascript - how to prevent form from sending with multiple validation checks?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

It seems that you can prevent a form from sending if your validation check returns false.

I have:

```
<form name="registration" action="registration.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <!-- some inputs like: -->
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
    <!-- and some others... -->
</form>
```

My validate() function in my javascript is made of multiple different checks though.

```
function validate() {
    checkUsername();
    checkPassword(); 
    checkFirstname(); 
    checkLastname();
    checkBirthdate();
    checkEmail();
    checkPhone();
}
```

There might be a case where the user inputs valid data for all of them except one. If that's the case, how do I tell validate() to still send 'false' back to the form, so that it doesn't submit?

Edit: If anyone is still reading this, for some reason my form is still sending. I even changed my validate() function so the only statement is "return false;" Do I have a syntax error or something?

Edit2: I found another solution that is simple, even if a little archaic. It overcame an issue I had where the function was only evaluating the first check and returning.

```
function validate() {
    var truth1 = checkUsername();
    var truth2 = checkPassword(); 
    var truth3 = checkFirstname(); 
    var truth4 = checkLastname();
    var truth5 = checkBirthdate();
    var truth6 = checkEmail();
    var truth7 = checkPhone();
    return (truth1 && truth3 && truth5 && truth2 && truth4 && truth6 && truth7);
}
```

Comment: Try calling `event.preventDefault()` before performing checks. If `true` is returned from all check calls, call `.submit()` on `form` element

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but it I thought there was an easier way. The example I based it off of was from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp, which was much simpler

Comment: @NicolasHassan The simplest approach would probably be to use `required` and `pattern` attributes at each element of `form`

Answer (score 3):

all your `individual field validation functions` should return a `boolean`.

then your `overall form validation function` will be

```
function validate() {
    var checks = [
        checkUsername,
        checkPassword,
        checkFirstname,
        checkLastname,
        checkBirthdate,
        checkEmail,
        checkPhone,
    ].map(function(check) { return check(); });

    return (checks.indexOf(false) === -1);
}
```

now ur validate function will return `false` if any field is invalid. `true` if all fields are valid

Comment: This makes sense but I'm having some trouble. Just to troubleshoot, I changed validate() so that all it does is "return false;"

however the form keeps sending anyway. Did I make a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: Hey Sagi, I was working through some other issues and I never got a chance to properly implement yours. The problem here is that it seems that by checkUsername returning "false", it prompts the function to stop checking the rest. Once checkUsername is satisfied, it still sends the form. Do you have any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: @NicholasHassan updated my answer, understood my mistake. thats why Array.prototype.every() was also not working it stops evaluation after the first false.

Comment: @NicolasHassan i mistakenly placed a ! Before the array that fails the checks.indexOf. i updated my answer to remove it. Try now

Comment: Thank you! I actually found another way to do it based on your method. I don't know if it's considered "proper" but it's certainly easier to explain. Check it out in my edit of the original post if you're interested!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.every()` to call each function, if any function returns `false`, `false` will be returned from `.every()` call

```
<form name="registration" action="registration.php">
    <!-- some inputs like: -->
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
    <!-- and some others... -->
</form>
```

```
function validate() {
    return [checkUsername, 
      checkPassword, 
      checkFirstname, 
      checkLastname, 
      checkBirthdate, 
      checkEmail,
      checkPhone].every(function(check) {return check()});
}

document.querySelector("[name=registration]")
.onsubmit = function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  if (validate()) { this.submit() }
  else { // notify user which fields are invalid }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "validate" function needs to return a "true" boolean result only when ALL of the individual check functions return a "true" result.

One way to do this is to modify each line in the current "validate" function to something like the following code.

```
bUsernameSts = checkUsername();
if !bUsernameSts { return false };
...
<other checks>
...
return true;
```

The only way the new "validate" function can return "true" is if all of the individual input validation checks were successful.